# Exporting the content of the html result to excel sheet

Tags: php, html, export-to-excel

I am trying to store the result oh html page to excel sheet in either .xlsx or .csv format.
Below is the snap shot of the result[image]

I am trying to save this content in excel sheet,
Below i have tried this php script but its printing only column heading but no data.

```
<?php
$file="demo.xls";
$test="<table  ><tr><td>Sl_No</td><td>Sample_ID</td><td>Run</td><td>Sequence</td><td>Obtained_read</td><td>Location</td></tr></table>";
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
echo $test;
?>
```

how to achieve this??
Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: If you're creating an Excel file using HTML markup, then you need to create the full markup, not simply the headers.... you actually need to generate the html for every row that you want included

Comment: full markup means?? if possible can youkindly edit the script??

Comment: If you want to create a real OfficeOpenXML file, then I'd recommend using a library like PHPExcel to do so

Comment: Full markup means that you need to include the actual data to display in your markup ($test)..... not simply one row of headers..... I can't edit your code because there's no code that shows where the data should come from, which means that I can't know where it comes from

Comment: by using the library can i give connection to that library from that download button??

Comment: No! You have to write the code to include the data that you want displaying in the spreadsheet

Comment: its a dynamic page, this is the one search result, how to show all the rows in every search??

Comment: If you already have code to generate that page, populating those two tables, then you need to repeat that code to retrieve the data again and build the Excel file, whether you do it via html markup, a csv or an OfficeOpenXML file..... or you need to cache the markup for the tables when you generate it for display, and use that cached markup/data in your export

Comment: i am using html markup